# Solve Two Functions In Three Variables and use ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am solving this system in mathematica

```
w = 0.1;
f3[a_, b_, x_] = w^2 x^5 + w (1 + a) x^4 + (a - b) x^3 - w;
f6[a_, b_, x_] = D[f3[a, b, x], x];
f7[a_, b_] := x /. NSolve[f6[a, b, x] == 0, x];
ContourPlot[f3[a, b, f7[a, b]][[1]] == 0, {a, -2, 0}, {b, -2, 0}]
```

I get Solve::ratnz error, but I do not see where the system is inexact.

Comment: Try with w = 1/10

Comment: That worked! Can I ask why that mattered?

Comment: @Louis Thanks for your help.

Comment: See [Exact and Approximate Results](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) and read the helps with the very instructive tutorials. Have fun!

Comment: Then you could answer your question itself, would be a brisk approach!

Comment: Ah, I see, basically a stupid mistake. I figured as much. Thanks again!